# Production Spark code started generating null pointers on count()

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application running using Spark on Hadoop (and Yarn) for a while in production. Recently, it started crashing on the call of count() function on a data frame. It gave a null pointer exception error. The session_frame data frame below is created by parsing a couple of text files and then joining them with data from a Hive table. Hive table is also updated separately once a day.

Code works fine on line 1 below but it fails on line 3 below after the condition. It was working fine so far.

```
line 1: session_frame.show(5)
line 2: clsd_frame = session_frame.where(col('time_stamp_col').isNotNull())
line 3: closed_sessions = clsd_frame.count()
```

To solve this problem, I tried to save the session_frame dataframe and decided to investigate what is wrong in the data. Surprisingly, when I saved it and load it again, there was no error on the count() function. So after line 1, I added two lines 1.1 and 1.2 to solve the issue:

```
Line 1.1: session_frame.write.........
line 1.2: session_frame=spark.read..........
```

What could be the reason of such an error? Could it be related to lazy evaluation when a count was trying to call all previous transformations on data frame? Could it be related to some sort of Hadoop and Yarn issue?

---

Here are some more details of how session data frame is created:

```
def process_sessions(data_frame, sessn_cols, code_list):
    cc = [col(i) for i in ["code", "tran_time"] + sessn_cols[3:]]
    re = [lit(';')] * (len(cc) * 2 - 1)
    re[0::2] = cc
   
    grup_frame = data_frame.withColumn('transactions_tmp', concat(*re)).groupBy('soc_sec').agg(collect_list(col('transactions_tmp')).alias('transactions_tmp'))

    schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("code", IntegerType(), False), StructField("time", TimestampType(), False)] + [StructField(cn, StringType(), False) for cn in sessn_cols[3:]]))

    ux_time = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:-2], '%Y%m%d%H%M')
    dt = lambda row: [line.split(';') for line in row]
    conv = udf(lambda row: [[int(line[0])] + [ux_time(line[1])] + line[2:] for line in dt(row)], schema)

    new_frame = grup_frame.withColumn('transactions', conv(col('transactions_tmp'))).drop(col('transactions_tmp'))
    #new_frame.show(5)

    sess_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("sess_id", StringType(), False), StructField("ssn", StringType(), False), \
        StructField("session_start", TimestampType(), False), StructField("session_end", TimestampType(), False), \
            StructField("plan_alias", StringType(), False), StructField("ip", StringType(), False)] \
                + [StructField(code, IntegerType(), False) for code in code_list] \
                    + [StructField(cn, StringType(), False) for cn in sessn_cols[4:]]))

    session_udf = udf(create_sessions, sess_schema)
    sess_frame = new_frame.withColumn('sessions', session_udf(col('transactions'), col('soc_sec'))).drop('transactions').drop('soc_sec')
    
    sess_frame = sess_frame.withColumn('sessions', explode('sessions'))
    sess_frame = sess_frame.select('sessions.*')
   
    return sess_frame
```

Comment: can you post full code ?? or are you overwriting same variable anywhere ??

Comment: No, variables are nor overwritten anywhere, as I mentioned code was running fine for a long time.  Full code is quite big to be posted here. We are calling UDFs and joins to create that mess_frame data frame. Only change that we made few weeks ago was a new code to update Hive table daily. This code however is independent of this code and runs separately. This code only loads data from that Hive table.

Comment: in line 1 session_frame .... . in line 2 sess_frame . where... . Please, show code where  sess_frame created or read data . Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the source code. Do you have any Action with session_frame before line 1? also please, details when you write and read. Where I can see col('time_stamp_col') ? What info in log Yarn?

Comment: Hi, I made one edit. I actually wrote it to HDFS after line 1 to solve this. Uptill line it is fine  and I can see results but error occurs on line 3 which means actually line 2 due to lazy evaluation.
Before line 1, there is one more action. sess_frame.union(past_session). past_sessions are coming from HDFS, they are open sessions.  But this is working fine as I can call show() after that.